# React Hook , setvariable and print in same useeffect

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I want to set name,room variable after axios calling and before socket.join. But SetName() is not working properly, and socket.join() is not receiving new value of Name, Room.
Name and Room value of set after socket.join() is completed, but I wanted is to set Name and Room value before socket.join()

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://localhost:5000/",
        mode: "cors",
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      const data = await response.data;
      await condition_check();
      await soc();
      function condition_check() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
          if (location.state === undefined) {
            SetConnected(true);
            SetValid(false);
          }
          if (data.status === "ok" && location.state !== undefined) {
            SetName(location.state.Name, () => {
              console.log(name);
            });
            SetRoom(location.state.Room);
            SetUserId(location.state.UserId);
            SetValid(true);
            resolve(console.log("1", name, room));
            SetConnected(true);
            SetSetup(true);
          }
        });
      }
      function soc() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (setup === true) {
            socket = socketIOClient.connect(ENDPOINT);
            socket.emit(
              "Join",
              { Name: name, Room: room, UserId: userid },
              (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  alert(err);
                }
              }
            );
            console.log("2", name, room);
            socket.on("message", ({ Name, Room, message, currenttime }) => {
              setMessages((messages) => [...messages, message]);
              setSenders((senders) => [...senders, Name]);
              setTime((time) => [...time, currenttime]);
              resolve(console.log(currenttime));
            });
          }
        });
      }
    })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// because `SetRoom` `SetName` is async

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "https://localhost:5000/",
        mode: "cors",
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      const data = await response.data;
      let NAME;
      let ROOM;
      await condition_check();
      await soc();
      function condition_check() {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
          if (location.state === undefined) {
            SetConnected(true);
            SetValid(false);
          }
          if (data.status === "ok" && location.state !== undefined) {
            ...
            NAME = location.state.Name
            ROOM = location.state.Room
            ...
          }
        });
      }
      function soc() {
        // use local variable `ROOM` and `NAME`
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          ...
        });
      }
    })();
```

Comment: It works, just a logic needed. It solved my many future problems.

Comment: so what's your problem

Comment: I had problems of using new state variable value in same useeffect. Now solved